# Meaning of "(On) Her Majesty's Secret Service"

Tags: meaning

The 1969 Bond Film was titled "**On** Her Majesty's Secret Service".

I have always wondered what was with the use of "On" in this phrase. Certainly, it should be "**In** Her Majesty's Secret Service"?

Is "On Her Majesty's Secret Service" even correct English? Does it mean anything?

Comment: You need to show your research when asking here.

Comment: Isn't a football player (of either variety) commonly said to be "*on* the team" of which he is a member?

Comment: Worth noting that in French, which had a lot of influence on English, our “in” and “on” both translate to the same single word.

Comment: @WGroleau: I don't think that's true; French has several prepositions corresponding to "in" and "on", such as *dans*, *en*, and *sur*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The preposition [on](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/on_1?q=on) has a number of different meanings depending on the context in which it is used.

In the case of "On Her Majesty's Secret Service", *on* is

> used to describe an activity or a state
>
> - to be on business/holiday/vacation
> - The book is currently on loan.

Let's look at the term ***to be on*** [active service](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/active-service)

> Someone who is on active service is taking part in a war as a member of the armed forces.

In James Bond's case he is "On Her Majesty's *Secret Service*"

This usage is mainly British.

As [Michael Harvey](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/44946/michael-harvey) pointed out in the comments:

[OHMS](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ohms)

> is used on official letters from British or Commonwealth government offices.

See Google images: [On Her Majesty's Service envelopes](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=On%20Her%20Majesty%27s%20Service%20envelopes&num=50&sa=X&authuser=1&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=2ahUKEwjHv8b3q4bdAhVFxhoKHVtDCq4Q7Al6BAgAEA0&biw=1536&bih=802#imgrc=ATj2gx3OI0bIMM:)

> OHMS is the abbreviation for 'On Her Majesty's Service' or 'On His Majesty's Service'.

[O.H.M.S](http://www.bfi.org.uk/films-tv-people/4ce2b74f67a59) also refers to a 1937 British comedy Film renamed [You're in the Army now](https://catalog.afi.com/Catalog/moviedetails/8706) for American audiences. The 007 movie was probably a play on words.

In American English [in service](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-service) would certainly apply.

> 2. in the armed forces

Comment: Until the 1970s, 'On Her Majesty's Service' used to be printed on all envelopes containing letters mailed out by UK government departments, sometimes abbreviated to 'OHMS'. I believe the film title could be, at least in part, a play on that.

Comment: I've shamelessly incorporated your comment into my answer. I sincerely hope it's not out of order :)

Comment: I am flattered that you found my comment useful, however you altered it slightly. 'On Her (or His) Majesty's Service' was usually printed in full on Government envelopes. 'OHMS' was found where there was not enough space for the full wording. [picture here](http://www.stampboards.com/images/locakart/PAT25-8305-3.jpg)

Comment: In British English, to be 'in service' has (had?) a specific meaning - to be employed as a domestic servant (butler, housemaid, etc).

Comment: I was going to mention _in service_ as also meaning being employed as a servant in a posh home but then decided not to.  I came across the term in Downton Abbey.

Comment: Not just 'posh' homes, right up to World War 2, middle class people like doctors, lawyers, bank managers, etc could afford a maid. The more well-off would have a maid living in the house, but it was cheaper to have a 'daily woman' who came in to cook, clean, etc. during the day. You should know that British people laugh at Downton Abbey for its hilarious inaccuracy.

Comment: Great answer, it explains a lot. But is this answer literally saying that they are basically identical synonyms? "On the Army" for example is actually correct english and with the same meaning as "in the army"?

Comment: @Jonathon Of course not!  With "On Her Majesty's Service", the "on" is being used in the same sense as "going away ON business", perhaps "on army business". James Bond, when on mission, was on very special business, indeed "On Her Majesty's Secret Service". He was also more generally "in the secret service" in the same way that someone might be "in the army".

Comment: The envelope @MichaelHarvey found seems to have "On Her/His Majesty's Service" printed _instead of a postage stamp_, to identify who is paying for having it sent -- so the "on" here would originally be the same "on" as in e.g. "buying something _on_ a company credit card".

Comment: Not quite, Henning. The 'On Her Majesty's Service' merely declares that the item is a government letter. Postage must still be paid. Instead of having a stamp, the envelope has been franked in a franking machine.  You can see the red wavy lines surrounding the words "OFFICIAL PAID", and  the round  postmark showing where and when the letter entered the postal system. It is a type of pre printed impression (PPI). The originating office or business declares to the Royal Mail the number of these used, and pays a bill monthly, usually at a discounted rate. Pre printed envelopes are also possible.

Comment: Indeed, the distribution office for this mail was where the US Embassy now stands.

Answer (score 3):

**On** is used here to indicate that Bond is a *member* of the Secret Service.  For reference, please refer to the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on) definition linked below.

> **on**
>   PREPOSITION
>   4 As a member of (a committee, jury, or other body)
>   ‘they would be allowed to serve on committees’

[source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on) - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on

For other examples of this type of usage,  consider the following sentence.

> "Tommy is on the debate team."

Comment: Could you please add something original to this answer? Stack Exchange answers should contain your own original work, not merely citations without explanations.

Comment: Perfect as a comment, less so as an answer. You should clearly attribute the definition.

Comment: Sources [MUST be attributed clearly in plain text](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), not merely as the destination of an apparently anonymous link. And I concur: without your own editorial content, this may well end up as a comment (at best).

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has this:

> *On Her Majesty's Secret Service* was written in Jamaica at Fleming's Goldeneye estate in January and February 1962, whilst the first Bond film, Dr. No was being filmed nearby. The first draft of the novel was 196 pages long and called *The Belles of Hell*. Fleming later changed the title after being told of a **nineteenth-century sailing novel** called *On Her Majesty's Secret Service*, seen by Fleming's friend Nicholas Henderson in Portobello Road Market.

[name of the novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Her_Majesty%27s_Secret_Service_(novel))

Found it: [On Her Majesty's Secret Service, at the British Library](http://explore.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/display.do?tabs=moreTab&ct=display&fn=search&doc=BLL01001657270&indx=17&recIds=BLL01001657270&recIdxs=6&elementId=6&renderMode=poppedOut&displayMode=full&frbrVersion=&frbg=&vl(488279563UI0)=any&dscnt=0&scp.scps=scope%3A%28BLCONTENT%29&tb=t&mode=Basic&vid=BLVU1&srt=rank&tab=local_tab&dum=true&vl(freeText0)=On%20her%20majesty%27s%20secret%20service&dstmp=1535127922038)

Title: *On Her Majesty's Secret Service*. [A novel.]

Publication Details: London : I. & R. Maxwell, 1878.

Identifier: System number 001657270

Physical Description: 314 p. ; 8º.

Shelfmark(s): General Reference Collection 12356.h.32.

UIN: BLL01001657270

To find out why it's titled like that, you'd have to read it. I see no author listed.

Comment: [On Her Majesty's Service](https://archive.org/details/168336800.1358.emory.edu) by Miss M.C. Hay?

Comment: I really have no idea. :)

Comment: I misedited the title and left out "secret". The recto page has other novels by Miss M.C. Hay. I love making assumptions and jumping to conclusions! :)

Comment: No worries at all. Yes, I do the same thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

One would not say, "on the service of my country..." it would, correctly be, "in the service of my country..." Likewise, "in service to Her Majesty, " and not, "on service to Her Majesty." Thusly, "in Her Majesty's Service (Secret or otherwise!)."

Comment: You should add some details and sources to back your interpretation up; the other answer's reason seems for more plausible right now.

Comment: What about ["On His/Her Majesty's Service"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_His_Majesty%27s_Service) which is written all over envelopes? Your argument seems to be entirely based on "one would not say…" but that's what one does say.